# Make ticks stop at graph in pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following plot:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}, compat=1.3}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Temperature Test},
    xlabel={Temperature [\textcelsius]},
    ylabel={Distance [m]},
    xmin=-50, xmax=140,
    ymin=0, ymax=7.5,
    xtick={-50, -30, -10, 10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110, 130},
    ytick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
    extra x ticks = {35.6},
    extra x tick labels = {},
    extra y ticks = {4.372},
    extra y tick labels = {},
    extra tick style = {
        major grid style = {red, solid, very thick}
        } ,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=*,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (-48,0.883)(18,1.852)(24,2.585)(52,6.891)(136,7.003)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{Graph of temperature against distance energy with critical point}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot]

I want the red lines (the **extra ticks**) to stop at the graph, like this:
[image]

How would I do this?

Also, I am relatively inexperienced with LaTeX, and especially new to making plots. So feel free to mention anything else in my code that could be improved; the above code was made by combining bits and pieces I could find on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is without the extra tick, just added another addplot:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny}, compat=1.3}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Temperature Test},
    xlabel={Temperature [\textcelsius]},
    ylabel={Distance [m]},
    xmin=-50, xmax=140,
    ymin=0, ymax=7.5,
    xtick={-50, -30, -10, 10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 110, 130},
    ytick={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=*,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (-48,0.883)(18,1.852)(24,2.585)(52,6.891)(136,7.003)
    };

\addplot[
color=red,very thick,
mark=none,
]
coordinates {
    (-50,4.372)(35.6,4.372)(35.6,0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{Graph of temperature against distance energy with critical point}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]